# $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f(x))^{a} dx$ , $0 < a < 1$ given $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

For any $f(x)$, are there any tricks to compute $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f(x))^{a} dx$ , $0 < a < 1$

given a known $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) dx$ ?

I thought differentiation under integral sign might lead me to something like this, but I couldn't get much further with that.

Comment: Contour integration seems very usable here.  Though I can't think up any general method.

Comment: It is not the case that the integral also exists, given some $f(x)$ and $a\in(0,1)$.

Comment: I don't really think this is possible. Consider $f=\chi_{(0,1)}$ and $f=2\chi_{(0,1/2)}$ and $\alpha=1/2$. Both have the same integral but when you take a square root you get two different results.

Comment: Indeed the latter does not determine the former.